# Java json date format not respected

Tags: java, json

In my dto, I use this way to get the correct value in the db.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="EST")
private Date birthdate;
```

If I insert 29/09/2015, I get the correct value in db.

When I display it, I get 2015-09-29 in html.

Why the JsonFormat is not used?

web to java is ok, so the problem is java to the web.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [Jackson Serialize Dates](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates)

In your class you have something like this:

```
 @JsonFormat
  (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
public Date eventDate;
```

Now, for testing the format you need to do something like this.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

String toParse = "20-12-2014 02:30:00";
Date date = df.parse(toParse);
Event event = new Event("party", date);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(event);
assertThat(result, containsString(toParse));
```

Check the link for more info.